# instead of class 'PlaceLikelihood'

Tags: java, android

In my Android code, the class `PlaceLikehood` and `PlaceLikelihoodBuffer` are deprecated as reported by the SDK.

Please suggest some alternatives of these classes?

Here is a segment of my code.

```
@Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
            int i = 0;
            LikelyPlaceNames = new String[MAXENTRIES];
            LikelyAddresses = new String[MAXENTRIES];
            LikelyAttributions = new String[MAXENTRIES];
            LikelyLatLngs = new LatLng[MAXENTRIES];

            for(Pling) placeLikelihoods.getPlace().getAddress();
            LikelyAttributions[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAttributions();
            LikelyLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

            i++;
            if(i > MAXENTRIES - 1 ) {
                break;
            }
        }
```